# Grouping 2 lines in to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may just be a Friday thing but I cant work out how to display these records as one line, my data looks like this

```
PTaskID     Part Requisition    Service Requisition
394512            Yes                   No
394512            No                   Yes
```

What I want is 1 row with the `PTaskID` but with the following, if there are more rows as in the example and one of them has a Yes in the `Part Requisition` then the overall row value for `Part Requisition` is Yes and the same logic should apply to `Service Requisition`.

Any help would be great PJD

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Load](
[PTaskID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Part Requisition] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
[Service Requisition] [varchar](3) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO Load (PTaskID, [Part Requisition], [Service Requisition])
VALUES
(394512,    'Yes',  'No'),
(394512,    'No',   'Yes')
```

Comment: Have you considered substituting `yes` and `no` with 1 and 0? That way you can do a `MAX()` statement. You can always use a `CASE` to translate them back to `yes` or `no` after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that 'Yes' comes after 'No' (*in most collations), you could `GROUP` and then do a `Max`, viz

```
SELECT PTaskID, MAX([Part Requisition]) as [MaxPartRequisition], 
                MAX([Service Requisition]) as  [MaxServiceRequisition]
FROM [Load]
GROUP BY PTaskID;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82189/1)

Comment: Hi Stuart, I never thought about using MAX in this way, good to learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Select Ptaskid, 
        case when sum(case when [Part Requisition] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)> 0 then  'Yes' else 'No' end 'Part Requisition',
        case when sum(case when [Part Requisition] = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)> 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end 'Service Requisition'
from [Load] 
group by ptaskid
```

Comment: Hi Azar, that worked a treat, I just needed to replace the second case statement "Part Requisition" with "Service Requisition" and all worked well with a number of combinations....thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This works better with any collation and also perfect

```
Select Ptaskid, 
        convert(varchar,max(CONVERT(varbinary, [Part Requisition]))),
        convert(varchar,max(CONVERT(varbinary, [Service Requisition])))

from [Load]
group by ptaskid
```